# Huge delay in getting ear deployed in weblogic

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, ear

I have a ear file which takes more than 40 minutes to get deployed in weblogic server. Can you please provide guidance on things that I need to look at in order to improve the deployment time?

Comment: Start with the server's logfile.

Comment: yes , I am looking at the logs & updated additional detaiils

Comment: can you please help in letting me know which weblogic log files that I need to look at? I looked at the app log and see intervals of 2-3 minutes between few STDOUT statements , but unable to determine what is happening during that period.

Answer (score 2):

I find that sometimes a Java security setting sometimes cause a very long start up delay.  This may or may not be relevant to you but see https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2344212

In `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security`
Replace 
`securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom`
with
`securerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom`

and note that the /./ is needed.

Comment: Thank you. Will explore this.

Answer (score 2):

the solution proposed by John K. is relevant only at the server startup, only on linux platforms. Have a look to your WebLogic Server log file under ${DOMAIN_HOME}/servers//logs/.log
Are you deploying your application with the admin console or using a wlst script ?

Thread dumps taken when application is deployed is also a very good source of information to see where WebLogic is spending time.

Answer (score 0):

Is your EAR file too big, is it greater than 500MB? If so, you could deploy some of the dependencies as libraries in weblogic and not deploy them with the application. Increasing JVM memory also helps. Some time restart the server before deploying your application also helps.

Comment: how can i do "you could deploy some of the dependencies as libraries in weblogic and not deploy them with the application"

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late to answer, but for anyone looking for the answer ->
pass this parameter when starting a weblogic:

```
-Dorg.jboss.weld.xml.disableValidating=true
```

It will disable XML schema validation - it was taking very long because some of URLs for XSD files were unavailable and weblogic took like forever to connect with those.

It will also help if your weblogic is working on environment without an Internet access.